# Highcharts | How to avoid Pie charts inside labels overlap

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart, overlap

I am using highcharts PIE, and want to put labels over the slices. But, since the smaller values are overlapped by the adjacent bigger values. I have set the "allowOverlap" property to false, This works well, until there is an update to the graph such as on hover event.

Hence:

```
pie.series.dataLabel.allowOverlap=false
```

doesn't persist between updates. Is there a way to handle such case?

References:

1. **Inside labels** - https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.dataLabels.inside.
2. **allowOverlap= false** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.dataLabels.allowOverlap

Answer (score 0):

There is no dataLabels.inside for series type of Pie, use dataLabels.distance instead. dataLabels.allowOverlap is undocumented for pie. This might explain the unexpected behaviour.

Seems like you are experiencing a bug, I would recommend submitting a bug report [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues).

Disabling mouse tracking, might be a temporary solution.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: null,
        plotShadow: false,
        type: 'pie',
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares in January, 2018'
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    accessibility: {
        point: {
            valueSuffix: '%'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                distance: -30,
                allowOverlap: false,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
            },
            enableMouseTracking: false,
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        type: 'pie',
        colorByPoint: true,
        dataLabels:{ allowOverlap: false},
        data: [{
            name: 'Chrome',
            y: 61.41,
            sliced: true,
            selected: true,
        }, {
            name: 'Internet Explorer',
            y: 11.84
        }, {
            name: 'Firefox',
            y: 10.85
        }, {
            name: 'Edge',
            y: 4.67
        }, {
            name: 'Safari',
            y: 4.18
        }, {
            name: 'Sogou Explorer',
            y: 1.64
        }, {
            name: 'Opera',
            y: 1.6
        }, {
            name: 'QQ',
            y: 1.2
        }, {
            name: 'Other',
            y: 2.61
        }]
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <p class="highcharts-description">
        Pie charts are very popular for showing a compact overview of a
        composition or comparison. While they can be harder to read than
        column charts, they remain a popular choice for small datasets.
    </p>
</figure>


<script src="index.js"></script>
```